# How to detect if system is being altered at any given moment?

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm creating whole filesystem snapshots (with BTRFS) periodically. I need to prevent my script from taking snapshots while system is an inconsistent state, such as in the middle of an application installation or a full system upgrade.

1. How can I reliably detect such actions?

Like we can not invoke multiple `apt` instances, I also want to create a lock for `apt install` (or any other package management software) in order to be sure that the snapshot operation has been finished (it may take a several seconds depending on disk IO).

2. How can I temporarily prevent any package management application from running?

Comment: You could grab the lock yourself, and either wait or fail (your choice) if you don't get it. While you have the lock, no software update will run. Be sure to release the lock when you exit, no matter how you exit.

Comment: Is there a central lock file where all the package managers have to regard? If yes, what is the path of this lock file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I reliably detect such actions?

`/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is apt's lock file, with which you can detect whether an apt operation is going on:

```bsh
if (( $(sudo lsof -t /var/lib/dpkg/lock | wc -w) > 0 )) ; then
    echo "dpkg is running."
fi
```

> How can I temporarily prevent any package management application from running?

Prevent the lock file from opening, eg. set the immutable attribute:

```
sudo chattr +i /var/lib/dpkg/lock  # "chattr -i" to release
```

Or, honestly, realize that the moment you start the snapshot defines what's in the snapshot. Storage might perform worse while the snapshot is made, but changes made after the start do not affect the snapshot itself.

In fact, a snapshot is a fairly lightweight thing - all it does is say "if you modify this block of data or metadata, make a copy of it, mark it as what's currently valid and mark this as what's valid for the last snapshot, and keep it". *Which is the totally normal mode of operation for a copy-on-write file system*. The difference is that when you've got data that's not part of a snapshot, the original after copying (and modifying the copy) gets returned to the pool of free extents/ metadata blocks.

Comment: The reason behind creating a lock file between start and end of snapshot operation is that I have multiple (~20) snapshots under the rootfs. Taking snapshots are sequential, so there is a time between first and last snapshots are taken.

Comment: um, that confuses me. Why do you take 20 snapshots of the same system?

Comment: There are lots of snapshots I intentionally created, like `/home/myuser`, `/home/myuser/VirtualBox VMs`, etc. because I may choose to exclude them while assembling the snapshots to create a separate bootable disk on a smaller disk. I also prefer creating `/var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs` as subvolumes because that allows easily rollback if something goes wrong with the containers. Moreover, there are lots of automatic subvolumes created by Docker. As you know, taking snapshot of rootfs excludes all of those snapshots, so I need to take those snapshots separately.

Comment: Ok, but then I'd recommend making sure only snapshotting the subvols actually affected by apt would block apt from running – /home/myuser certainly won't be touched by software updates, neither would be your VMs.

Comment: How do we check if `dpkg` is running by looking at `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file? It always exists, so checking its existence is nonsense. `flock -x` or `flock -s` also doesn't work. `lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` returns nothing while `apt-get update` is running. Can you show the exact code to demonstrate getting and setting the lock?

Comment: @ceremcem in apt's source code, [`fileutl.cc`](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/apt-pkg/contrib/fileutl.cc#L243) has the `GetLock` method used underneath. It's a bit more complicated than just calling `flock`.